# Directory in /proc that isn't process dir but start with number?

Tags: linux, process, proc

Quick question. Is it possible to create directory in /proc that starts with number but isn't process directory (where name is PID)? I write software that searches for process directories and I wonder what conditions should I check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No part of the official kernel currently does that, nor any third-party kernel module that I've seen. Only a kernel component could do that.

I think that `/proc/[0-9]*` is common enough in shell scripts that no official kernel component will ever do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create manually (in the usual way) a directory in `/proc` because it is not really a filesystem: it's a way for the kernel to show system and process information in a hierarchical, filesystem-like structure.

The only way someone could create a directory under `proc` is by writing a kernel module that does so, but that would mess up things quite a bit.  So I think it's safe for you to assume `/proc/[0-9]*` always relate to processes.